# how can I convert react-native data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars, agenda

```
// i have to change my data to this form
items={{
'2021-04-20': [{name: 'item 1 - any js object'}],
'2012-04-21': [{name: 'item 2 - any js object'}]
}}
```

I am trying to show data below using react-native calendar library's agenda. And agenda needs the form of data like above.

```
['20210420': 'work', '20210421': 'sleep'] //the data i have
```

how can i convert my data by using react-native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you!

```js
const data = {'20210420': 'work', '20210421': 'sleep'}
const formattedData = {}
Object
.entries(data)
.forEach(([key, value]) => formattedData[`${key.substr(0, 4)}-${key.substr(4, 2)}-${key.substr(6)}`]= [{ name: value }])
console.log(formattedData)
```